# Prepend text to all commands in terminal mode

Tags: vimrc, terminal-buffer

I would like to prepend `clear;` to all commands in terminal mode. This reduces the amount of 'clutter' in my terminal screen and makes things slightly clearer for me.

Comment: I'm not sure that affecting the shell like that is something you can do from Vim. May be better to ask at Unix & Linux SE how you would enable that in Bash (or whatever). Then from the Vim side you might be able to set an environment variable, inherited by terminal launched shells only, that enables whatever you figure out for the shell end.

Comment: It may help you to know that vim sets the `VIM_TERMINAL` environment variable on unix systems ([`:h terminal-unix`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-unix)) which  you could exploit in your shell's initialisation files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash and Zsh, a `DEBUG` trap can be used to chain a given set of commands or function
to each issued command. Thus,

```
trap 'clear; "$@"' DEBUG
```

solves your problem.

Presumably you do not want to do it manually every single time, nor to affect every
interactive shells, only those in Vim's terminal buffer.
In that case, the solution is to add this to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file:

```
[ -n "$VIM_TERMINAL" ] && trap 'clear; "$@"' DEBUG
```

The test verifies if the [`VIM_TERMINAL`](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/terminal.html#terminal-unix) environment variable is set;
if yes, it sets the trap.